# Remove borders or margin from all pdf pages using pdfbox

Tags: java, c#, pdfbox, pdfminer

I'm currently working on a project where I use pdfbox to extract the content from a pdf with the format intact to a text file, however for few of the pdf’s the formatting is lost. It's because of the unstructured tabular structures in this pdf template.

Comment: Please add what you have done so far to the question.

Comment: I removed the iText tag because your question is not about iText.

Comment: Please try the sort option and share your pdf.